# How to start building a django website with postgres nginx and gunicorn on separate machines?

Tags: django, database, nginx, server, gunicorn

I searched all over the internet and I guess I'm lost, Please I want a detailed answer here.

I know how to make all three of these things(gunicorn, Nginx, and Postgres) work on the same machine but what if I wanna have all of them on the different/individual machine.

Let's say I got 3 behemoth powerful machines capable of handling anything but the real question in my mind is where do I start. how can I connect all three of these together? what if I wanna add more storage? How do I connect multiple database machines together

I'm sorry but I'm pretty new in networking and it's really crucial for me to understand this because if I don't my mind won't allow me to go ahead with the process.

Comment: You don't set these services up on different machines, you have them all running on each machine (apart from the database perhaps), and distribute the traffic between them as it increases. Take a look into scaling django. AWS provides load balancers & auto scaling to distribute load & control the number of servers. Give this a read; https://djangobook.com/scaling-django/

Comment: ok so how I separate database with both nginx and gunicorn

Comment: try to ask on https://serverfault.com. This is a networking / server admin question. You may find more skilled guys there.